# Django: Autogenerate Click To Tweet link

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In my *helpers* folder, I have in my `__init__.py` the following method that will autogenerate the link:

```
def autogenerate_click_to_tweet_if_needed(production):
    """
    # We check if the click to tweet associated with this production
    # needs to be auto-generated. We only do this if it is NULL or empty
    # so that if user entered it manually it prevales.
    :param production:
    """
    if not production:
        return

    # 1. We check if the production meets the requirements for a click to tweet.
    #    If it does not we delete all click to tweet associated with the production.
    #    Criteria is to be Published.
    meets_criteria = production.status() == 'Published'
    if not meets_criteria:
        ClickToTweetProductionTweet.objects.filter(production=production).delete()
        return

    # 2. We get the first and only click to tweet for this production.
    click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet.objects.filter(production=production).first()
    # If we have a valid text in the tweet, we just return as we will not
    # modify an existing one.
    if click_to_tweet and click_to_tweet.tweet:
        return

    # 3. We get the format for the tweet from the Podcast.
    #    if we have no valid format then do nothing
    tweet_format = production.podcast.podcast_click_to_tweet_format
    if not tweet_format:
        return

    # 4. If we do not have a click to tweet we create one.
    if not click_to_tweet:
        click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet(production=production)

    # 5. We will make the necessary an possible substitutions on the format
    #    to compose the tweet text.
    #    Valid placeholders are:
    #    PODCAST_TWITTER_NAME = podcast_twitter_name (in podcast)
    #    PODCAST_GUEST_TWITTER_NAME = podcast_guest_twitter_name (in podcast)
    #    WORDPRESS_URL = wordpress_url (in production)
    tweet_format = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(tweet_format, 'PODCAST_TWITTER_NAME',
                                                                      production.podcast.podcast_twitter_name)
    tweet_format = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(tweet_format, 'PODCAST_GUEST_TWITTER_NAME',
                                                                      production.podcast.podcast_guest_twitter_name)
    wordpress_url = production.wordpress_short_url if production.wordpress_short_url else production.wordpress_url
    tweet_format = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(tweet_format, 'WORDPRESS_URL', wordpress_url)
    tweet_format = smart_text(tweet_format)

    # 6. Update and save
    click_to_tweet.tweet = tweet_format
    click_to_tweet.save()
```

Under my `ProductionTweet` class in `models.py`, I have the following method where I can grab the link:

```
def click_to_tweet_link(self):
        base_url = settings.CLICK_TO_TWEET_BASE_URL
        if not base_url:
            return None
        return base_url + self.slug
```

Here is the view for the tweet section in `views.py`:

```
class EpisodeClickToTweet(ProductionRequiredMixin, View):
    form_class = EpisodeClickToTweetForm
    template_name = 'fc/forms_clicktotweet.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_values = {}
        # See if we already have a click to tweet for this production, if so get id
        click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet.objects.filter(production_id=self.production.id).first()

        initial_values['production_id'] = self.production.id
        initial_values['id'] = click_to_tweet.id if click_to_tweet else None
        initial_values['tweet'] = click_to_tweet.tweet if click_to_tweet else None

        form = self.form_class(initial=initial_values)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # lets get the data
            production_id = form.cleaned_data.get('production_id')
            id = form.cleaned_data.get('id')
            tweet = form.cleaned_data.get('tweet')

            #A production must exist, othewise 404
            production = get_object_or_404(Production, id=production_id)

            if id:
                click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet.objects.get(id=id)
            else:
                click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet(production=production)

            click_to_tweet.tweet = tweet
            click_to_tweet.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fc:episodeschedule', kwargs={'production_id':production_id}))

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Its form:

```
from django import forms

class EpisodeClickToTweetForm(forms.Form):
    production_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)
    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)
    tweet = forms.CharField(max_length=80, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add Tweet Text', }))
```

And template:

```
{% extends "fc/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="87.5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 87.5%">
    <span class="sr-only">87.5% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default box-shadow--16dp col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="panel-body">

<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-12'>

<h3>Setup | Add Episode</h3>

<h4>Twitter - Guest Click-To-Tweet</h4>

<h5>FC will also build the ‘clickable tweet’ which will be automatically sent in the body of the mail to your guest on the morning of the episode goes live.</h5>

<hr/>

<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}

<hr/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary box-shadow--6dp"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i> Continue
</button>

</form>

</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

So to recap:

1. Additional button where it can generate the click to tweet link
2. Another field where it will display the link that just created

How would be the best approach for this?

**Would appreciate any help or suggestions :)**